# Finding the time stamp for an autofill entry in Google Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, sync

My pc was stolen and I had Chrome with sync active on it.

Now I'm login into Chrome from a new pc and I'm seeing an autofill entry with a name and address I don't recognize, my theory is that it must be an autofill used by someone who has the computer now (the robber or a 2nd hand buyer)

I can use SQlite browser but I have no idea where to look for the synced autofill records so I can check the create date. Any ideas?

Comment: Ha! That’s awesome. If only all criminals could be this dumb. So what happened? Did you give the address to the police to track down?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Download [SQLite Database Browser](http://sqlitebrowser.sourceforge.net). Head over to `%localappdata%\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default` and copy `Web Data` file to a separate folder.

Now open Web Data with the SQL Lite browser. Click on Execute SQL and type

```
SELECT *
FROM   autofill
WHERE  VALUE LIKE 'your-autofill-entry'
```

[image]

Make a note of the pair id,  and type in

```
SELECT *
FROM   autofill_dates
WHERE  pair_id = number-obtained-from-above-step
```

That'll get you the Unix epoch of when the autofill entry was created

[image]

Head over to [Epoch converter](http://www.epochconverter.com/) and you'll get the Epoch converted to the date/time you're familiar with.

Comment: Worked brilliantly, thanks for the clear post with the screenshots.

Comment: glad to help @Pedro!